# Hamming Window, python 2.7

Tags: signal-analysis, python, window-functions, numpy

Hi I have a FFT which is quite noisy. How to apply to my code Hamming window to make it less noisy. Look at my code:

```
# Loop for FFT data
for dataset in [fft1]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    psd = np.abs(np.fft.fft(dataset))
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(dataset.size, float(300)/dataset.size)
    plt.semilogy(freq[freq>0], psd[freq>0]/dataset.size**2, color='r')

for dataset2 in [fft2]:
    dataset2 = np.asarray(dataset2)
    psd2 = np.abs(np.fft.fft(dataset2))
    freq2 = np.fft.fftfreq(dataset2.size, float(300)/dataset2.size)
    plt.semilogy(freq2[freq2>0], psd2[freq2>0]/dataset2.size**2, color='b')
```

I put an answer in the questions.

Comment: Hamming window doesn't denoise – it reduces spectral leakage, so I'm not sure you're going in the right direction at all. Why are you doing a DFT in the first place? What's the goal of all this? My gut feeling tells me that you should probably be applying Welch's method (or Bartlett, which is Welch with 0 overlap), or a different frequency or spectrum estimator alltogether.

Comment: Well those are good questions. I am trying to receive a spectra of Schumann Resonance. I have a measurements from every 5 minutes. I am new to python and signal processing, so my answers and questions might not be precise. Do You have any ideas how you might help me?

Comment: Ah, a wild physicist appears! I have no idea what "Schumann Resonance" is, but what exactly is your requirement for the spectrum you're trying to estimate? The optimal way to help you is by trying to understand which problem you're trying to solve, and any background you can give on what you want to do with the results would definitely be worth being *in the question itself*, rather than in some comment that aside from me no-one will ever read.

Comment: Thank you for trying at least. Ok, so I will upgrade my question with the rest of the code so you might be able to understand it better :) But some info for you, Schumann Resonance appears when there is a thunder strike in the atmosphere, it makes a resonance between the ionosphere and the ground. This resonance appears in +/- 8Hz, so that's why I need FFT of my data. I will reedit my question with more code and photos.

Comment: Ah, "so I need FFT of my data" is, I think, a fallacy. What you want to estimate is the *spectrum*, and the FFT (which is just an implementation of the DFT, by the way), is just one way to estimate spectra. It's a non-parametric one, and it gives your equal resolution all over your observation bandwidth. What your problem actually demands is a spectrum estimator that is "fine" close to the frequencies you care about, has low variance with the same amount of data, and estimates a discrete set of oscillations with known parameters – so, I'd argue that the FFT is a very suboptimal approach here.

Comment: So, if you could state the number of samples you have, and the frequency resolution you need (and where in spectrum you need it, if possible to say), that would be very helpful in suggesting a method. For a quick and easy test: split your samples in 4 equally long parts. Make 4 FFTs, average, and only then do the abs(). (by the way, abs(dft(signal)) doesn't give you a PSD, should be abs(dft(signal))²!)

Comment: That should significantly reduce your noise variance == noise power. But there's methods that are far cleverer than Bartlett's method (which I just described for 4 subwindows)!

Comment: Seems like you know your topic, unlike me. Well the number of samples is 266336, but as you can see in fft1 and fft2 I have cut some data, because they were errors. Well my first measurements are in 60Hz, but I also need in 300Hz, but about the resolution I need to see the difference in 8Hz (Schumann Resonance), it will appear as a small peak it might be seen on the charts which I have posted, but it is not very clear, that's why I need a view like in the second chart, which I have put as an example.

Comment: hey, can you really go and **edit** your question to include these facts rather than giving them in the comments? That way, I can more easily address them.

Comment: and I don't understand your resolution requirement, to be honest.

Comment: Added some info in question.

Comment: "my first measurements have spectrum of 60Hz, but I also need in 300Hz." <- this sentence, sadly, makes no sense! Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I have changed it.

Comment: "that kind of resolution" is also nothing I understand. Whatever you can put in formulas, please put in formulas.

Comment: I have 887,786 samples in one second which gives 266336 in 300 seconds.  So the sampling frequency is 0,003Hz

Comment: um, no, that is not right. If you have 887786 samples in one second, your sampling rate is 887786 Hz. Anyway, what does that have to do with the resolution *requirement* of your spectrum? All I'm asking you is how large the difference between two frequency components that you need to tell apart are allowed to be.

Comment: There is a comma you have missed

Comment: I have 266336 samples in 300 seconds, and in every second 887,786 samples are made if you multiply 887,786 by 300 seconds, you will receive 266336 samples.

Comment: ah, I was in American mode. Anyway, your sampling rate is really number of samples you get per second. That's the meaning of the word.

Comment: Ok then, thanks for explaining :) So can you help me somehow with the code or something? I know there are many things I need to learn.

Comment: so, that gives you 2666336/300 $\approx$ 1000 samples per second, or approximately 1kHz of sampling rate, not 0,003 Hz

Comment: again, the way to help you is to understand your problem. There's no shortcut here. You haven't sufficiently described your problem, so I can't describe a solution. I thought that was a concept pretty easy to understand for a scientist like you!

Comment: Everybody begins with something, I have a huge lack of knowledge in signal processing, but I at least try to correct it. Thank you for trying to help. I'll make some research about my problem and what I need, and then I will try to ask You again.

Comment: Thanks! I really think your problem is exciting, and I hope that the Bartlett method that I already mentioned gets you a small step forward; I'd be really interested in hearing what you need to achieve, because honestly, I still have no idea what it is that you want to have in the end.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69656/discussion-on-question-by-hiddenguy-hamming-window-python-2-7).

Comment: `# Loop for FFT data  </br>
for dataset in [fft1]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    freqs, psd = welch(dataset, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=8192)
    plt.semilogy(freqs, psd/dataset.size, color='r')

for dataset2 in [fft2]:
    dataset2 = np.asarray(dataset2)
    freqs2, psd2 = welch(dataset2, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=8192)
    plt.semilogy(freqs2, psd2/dataset2.size, color='b')`

This code is the answer for my question. Topic closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact Welch was a good idea. End of post. Problem solved.

```
# Loop for FFT data
for dataset in [fft1]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    freqs, psd = welch(dataset, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=8192)
    plt.semilogy(freqs, psd/dataset.size**2, color='r')

for dataset2 in [fft2]:
    dataset2 = np.asarray(dataset2)
    freqs2, psd2 = welch(dataset2, fs=266336/300, window='hamming', nperseg=8192)
    plt.semilogy(freqs2, psd2/dataset2.size**2, color='b')
```

Comment: watch your integer division! `fs=266336/300` is 887.786666… in Python3 (which you **should** be using, as Python 2 is going to be obsolete), but 887 in Python 2.